# determine if file descriptor is closed

Tags: shell, posix

In posix sh, is it possible to determine if a file-descriptor is open?

I've got an optional input file descriptor to a script for a user supplied extension and a read will immediately fail with `EBADF`.

```
#!/bin/sh
database_initialize()
{
   echo "create database bob;"
  # TODO check if open
  # Input file descriptor 3 is used to send to bootstrap
  cat <&3

}

database_initialize | mysqld --bootstrap
```

I'd like to avoid Linux specific things like `[ -s /proc/self/fd/3 ]`

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): [Testing if a file descriptor is valid](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/206786)

Comment: Very similar, wordings very much around writable file descriptors however thanks for the link @StéphaneChazelas, `if { >&3; } 2> /dev/null` proved nice as a small variant of your answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fd_is_open() (: >&"$1") 2>/dev/null;

if fd_is_open 7; then
   ...
fi
```

This gives a false positive for fd 2, since we have to open it in order to silence the error messages.

Comment: Can be shortened to `fd_is_open() (: >&"$1") 2>/dev/null`, or to avoid the fork: `fd_is_open(){ >&"$1"; } 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: The latter triggers some (nonstandard?) zsh feature -- it tries to read from stdin: `zsh -c 'fd_is_open(){ >&"$1"; } 2>/dev/null; fd_is_open 1 && echo yes; echo done'`

Comment: Note that this does not work with the historic Bourne Shell because this shell does not check the return code of the `dup()` call. The existence of this bug has been discovered in 2016 and fixed in `bosh`.